# Regex Negation on a set of strings

Tags: php, regex, string, regex-negation

In the following string:

```
<table  border="1"><tr><td class=" m" bgcolor="#cccccc" style="bold" size="7" m="m "><span></span> </td><td class=" m" bgcolor="#cccccc" style="bold" size="7" m="m " align="center">NAMES </td><td class=" m" bgcolor="#cccccc" style="bold" size="7" m="m " colspan="13" align="center">AREAS </td></tr></table>
```

I'd like to remove all attributes other than the following: border,bgcolor and class.

```
^(?:border|class|bgcolor)\b))=".*?"
```

doesn't work out. Any suggestions please?

Comment: You can use a regex for that. But it's only advisable for output transformation, not as security feature. A regex would be too much overhead to cover the various legal serializations.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_replace('/ (?!(border|class|bgcolor))[^=" ]+="[^"]*"/', '', $str);
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?2vp0m

---

That said, [please don't use a regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454)!!!

Comment: +1 for a good answer (and thanks for the link to RegExr, I hadn't seen it before - looks useful!)

Comment: @StuartGolodetz - I use it here for all my answers on regex's. It's the easieat way to demonstrate that what you're doing actually works!